# Using Promises on if statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, async-await

I'm trying to use Promises under an if condition. The problem I am facing is even when the if statement is false, the code under it still executes. How would I fix this bug?

Example here but full code in the link: https://jsbin.com/qezimeyopo/edit?js

```js
//MAIN TRAILING STOPLOSS
async function binanceTrailingSLOrder(symbol, orderId, quantity, oldPrice, percentage, active) {

  const clean_trade = client.ws.trades([symbol], async trade => { //run websocket
    var livePrice = parseFloat(binance_symbols[symbol]["close"]); //set new price to live price
    console.log("1) order ID: " + orderId + " active: " + active);

    if (active == true) {
      try {
        const orderStatus = await binanceCheckOrderStatus(symbol, orderId);

        console.log("2) order ID: " + orderId + " active: " + active + ", new SL: " + (oldPrice * ((100 + percentage) / 100)));

        switch (orderStatus.status) {
          case "NEW":
          case "PENDING":
            console.log("Still running ...");

            if (livePrice >= (oldPrice * ((100 + percentage) / 100)) && active == true) {
              active = false;
              const cancelOrder = await binanceCancelOrder(symbol, orderId);

              if (cancelOrder) {
                console.log("Old SL cancelled");
                var newSL = livePrice * ((100 - percentage) / 100);
                newSL = binanceNormalizePrice(symbol, newSL);

                try {
                  const newStopLoss = await binanceStopOrder(symbol, 'SELL', quantity, newSL, newSL);

                  if (newStopLoss) {
                    orderId = newStopLoss.orderId;
                    quantity = newStopLoss.origQty;
                    oldPrice = livePrice;
                    active = true;
                  }
                } catch (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              }
            }
            break;
          default:
            console.log("Final case: " + orderStatus.status);
            break;
        }

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```
/*
Algorithm:

 1. Run websocket to recieve price in realtime
 2. Check if the order is still active
 3. If yes, and price is higher x%:
    a. cancel old order
    b. update new order
*/
```

The bug I am facing is, even when active is false, the `console.log("2) order ID: ...` still executes as shown in this image:
[image]

Comment: It's pretty much the same, I only removed some irrelevant stuff like the switch cases and a couple console logs.

Comment: In the jsbin link I shared, I've shown other functions that I use within the main `binanceTrailingSLOrder` function..

Comment: So according to the binance-api-node API, the `clean_trade()` will stop the running websocket (which is the `const clean_trade` variable). In the picture I put up, not until the stoploss is hit, the `clean_trade` is irrelevant.

Comment: The specific place I am recieving an error at is the first console log after the `if active == true`. It shouldnt execute because the code is not supposed to enter the if statement in the first place. However, if you want me to share the exact code in the picture, I will update the jsbin :)

Comment: nah, pictures of code are boring ... can you write some code that actually demonstrates the problem? as it is, even the jsbin code doesn't run at all, let alone demonstrate the error you are claiming

Comment: Did you notice that order is gettting executed 26 times?  IOW: Your explaining your problem like a linear issue, and it looks more like a recurrent one.

Comment: it's probably how `binanceTrailingSLOrder2` is called ... and since that's not shown anywhere, that's probably the problem

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is that the variable `active` at the outer function scope is getting mutated by the parallel operations, which is probably why the `console.log` for the variable is giving unexpected results.

Comment: `client.ws.trades([symbol], async trade => {` <== this callback is being called multiple times in such a way that your `active` flag is pointless, du to the `await` inside `if active == true` - that's the only explanation as to why active could be made false between the `if` and the `console.log`

Comment: i.e. an inrush of data on the websocket could trigger many callbacks - and asynchrony will take care of the rest

Comment: see if [this helps](https://jsfiddle.net/8j1rmdy4/) that will process each incoming `trade` sequentially

Comment: How often is `binanceTrailingSLOrder` called, and what is `client.ws.trades`?

Comment: +1 to what @JaromandaX said. You probably want to check the `active` flag *after* the `await binanceCheckOrderStatus`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem most likely stems from mutliple async functions sharing a single variable `active`. Some pseudo-code with the gist of the problem:

```
function processAllOrders(symbol, active) {
  client.doForAllOrdersWithSymbol(symbol, async (order) => {
    console.log("Active before await: ", active)

    if (active) {
      const status = await order.getStatus() // execution waits here

      // So active could have changed in the meantime...
      console.log("Active after await: ", active)
      if (status === 'whatever') {
        active = false // <- changes active variable
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Since the function is executed for multiple orders, the first one which randomly arrives at the statment will change the active parameter for all orders. Since you have an **await** statment after the first console.log the value of active can change while execution is waiting.